# Qt5.7 installed on Raspberry Pi3 and working...how to get QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, raspberry-pi3, qt5.7

I've finally mangaged to get Qt5.7 on a Raspberry Pi3, and have built an example which runs on the Pi, this was done by carefully following:

[Step by Step instructions on how to install Qt5.6 on Raspberry Pi3](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step)

To get 5.7 on the Pi simply replace:

```
    git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git -b 5.6
```

With:

```
    git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git -b 5.7
```

This sets-up the tool chain on a Linux host in my case Ubuntu 16.04, however it doesn't install QtCreator, I then tried installing QtCreator and messed up the build, so I had to start over.

How do I get the latest QtCreator installed on either the Ubuntu 16.04 or preferably on the Pi3 ?

Answer (score 1):

I just started following these instructions: https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-raspberry-pi

It starts with installing QtCreator on the Desktop, as you are cross compiling, why would you want it on the Pi itself?

Still waiting for the build to complete, wonder if it will all work right away :)

Comment: Who said I wanted to cross compile?  I wanted to get the whole lot working stand alone.

Comment: Ow, then I think you should build it on the Pi, do nothing on the Host of course. https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi